Lost Samsung Galaxy A22 locked out when doing setup due to switched Google account
I lost my Samsung Galaxy A22 (SM-A225F/DS) and got it back from the police who found it and returned it to me. The problem that I encountered was that my phone was locked when I received it, so I decided to reset it.
I already reset it, and I encountered another problem when I'm doing a setup because it need the Google account for the verification, but when I enter my Google account that I used in my lost phone here, it is changed to the Google account of the one who stole it.
Therefore, I cannot complete the setup to my phone because of that, and instead of using the Google account, it needed the pattern unlock to unlock it, but I don't know the pattern of it. So I'm here to seek help.

Probably help: How to bypass Factory Reset Protection (FRP) or "Verify your account" screen?

This doesn't sound right to me.  The thief would have to know your Google account and receive verification before they could change it to their account.  Similarly, if you had a lock code, it would take a while to try each combination, so that's unlikely.  I would suggest that it is not your phone.  What makes you think its your phone?

This question is similar to: How to bypass Factory Reset Protection (FRP) or "Verify your account" screen?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
